# Converter data do formato yyyyymmdd para dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma string com o seguinte valor: **20191219** 
trata-se de uma data no formato ano mês e dia, queria saber como faz para transformar ela para o formato dia/mes/ano, usando o valor que mencionei, ficaria 19/12/2019.

Pesquisando na internet vi que tem o Date.parse(), mas só daria certo se essa string fosse quebrada com *espaços*, */* ou *-*

Pensei em usar substring para capturar as posições, pegando o ano, mês e dia, e com isso montar no formato que eu quero, no entanto, eu imagino que deva existir uma forma mais fácil de fazer isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a data sempre estiver no formato `YYYYMMDD`, você pode usar uma expressão regular para fazer o *match* de cada parte individual da data.

Algo assim:

```js
function parseDate(dateString) {
  const [, year, month, day] = dateString.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/)
  
  return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
}

console.log(parseDate('20191219'));
```

Basicamente, criamos a seguinte expressão regular:

```
/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/
```

Ela possui três grupos:

- O primeiro deles, que corresponde ao ano, formado por 4 dígitos — capturado por `\d{4}`, que significa 4 dígitos;
- O segundo grupo, que corresponde ao mês, formado por 2 dígitos — capturado por `\d{2}`;
- E o último deles, correspondente ao dia, formado por 2 dígitos — também capturado por `\d{2}`.

Em seguida usamos o método `match`. Para saber mais sobre ele, leia [a documentação do `String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: Show de bola, muito obrigado, sabia que teria uma forma mais eficaz, com isso eu posso até fazer o caminho inverso para salvar uma nova data no banco

Answer (score 1):

Cara consegui contorna esse problema no meu sistema de uma forma mais simples

Eu tenho um input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-default" placeholder="Data final de pagamento" name="data_vencimento" required="required"  maxlength="10" onkeypress="mascaraData(this)">
```

No banco de dados eu declarei um varchar de 10 e no input coloquei um maxlength="10"

Ai fiz uma mascaraData(this) em javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mascaraData(data){ 
        if(data.value.length == 2)
            data.value = data.value + '/'; 
        if(data.value.length == 5)
            data.value = data.value + '/';
    }
</script>
```

Toda vez que a pessoa digitar ele vai alto incrementar as barras e vai limitar a 10 digitos e no banco de dados como vai estar varchar, ele ira salvar a data no formato brasileiro.